# if statement says true to a null variable

Tags: php

What is happening here? Is it to late for my brain?

I have a php file containing **exaclty** the code below.

```
<?php

$foo = 'foo';

$bar = null;

switch ($foo) {
    default:
    case 'foo':
        if ($bar) {
            echo 'true';
        } else {
            echo 'false';
        }
}
```

Prints `true` when run in the browser but `false` when run on command line... HOW? I noticed when I remove the line `default:` it works, but how should this whole switch statement be related to this? It's still a simple `if (null) { doing this anyway }`

**PHP 7.0.13**
**Apache/2.4.18**

And yes... I cleared my browser cache, hit ctrl+f5... I even changed the scripts file name.

**UPDATE:**
After making changes to this simple file... (just adding whitespaces to the end) and hitting f5 in the browser it says `false` **once** but than `true` again... no matter what I do. I really don't get it.

**UPDATE:**
My PHP version just got updated from 7.0.13 to 7.0.15. Guess what... still the same output:

**Apache/Browser: true**

**Console: false**

Comment: I think because you have put the default statement in the start.

Comment: @Abbas So what? Theres still an if clause which should prevent the first var_dump.

Comment: By the way when i execute your code in my side it is printing the 'else'

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/964ee98ee404d65ef27c44778cf5c9695b82331b

Comment: [Seems to work as expected](https://3v4l.org/VMGcI)

Comment: it's definitely too late for your brain. ;) works as expected on my local php7.

Comment: Of course.... I see it's working in the online sandboxes but on my local machine it behaves like i describe, honestly! Just a single php file containing exactly the above code. php 7.0.13

Comment: Have you omitted any code? Is `$bar` getting redefined anywhere? The link Mark provided (3v4l) tests all versions of PHP including 7.0.13

Comment: I get false all the time as expected. I'm in PHP 5.6.24. Maybe you have 'nul', between quotes.

Comment: may I ask why the default is the first option? what happens if you put it after the 'foo' case?

Comment: @Xorifelse Checked that... It's the same php version on cli and apache... 7.0.13

Comment: @Xorifelse Yes maybe... see my latest update on the question. I'm just very puzzled about that when I remove the `default:` the output is correct.

Comment: @Xorifelse I know.... did that... restarted my computer now and apache several times.... still the same output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134538/discussion-between-xorifelse-and-markus-kottlander).

Comment: I've verified that both the cli and Apache both use the same version and the output varies between both of them. I am out of idea's, except an update of the PHP version if its available. I'll delete my previous comments to make the comment section more readable.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
<?php
$foo = 'bar';

$bar = null;

switch ($foo) {
    default:
    case 'bar':
        if (isset($bar)) {
            echo "true";
            die();
        } else {
            echo "false";
            die();
        }
}
```

This code will echo `false`.

You could also use a double not operator:

```
<?php
$foo = 'bar';

$bar = null;

switch ($foo) {
    default:
    case 'bar':
        if (!!$bar) {
            echo "true";
            die();
        } else {
            echo "false";
            die();
        }
}
```

**The problem with your `default` case**

In the code you provided (and the code I re-quoted), you will be hitting `case 'bar'` every time, no matter what `$foo` is set to.

```
<?php
$foo = 'notbar';

$bar = null;

switch ($foo) {
    default:
    case 'bar':
        if (!!$bar) {
            echo "true";
            die();
        } else {
            echo "false";
            die();
        }
}
```

This code will still echo `false`.

What you should do is include a `break` in the default case.

```
<?php
$foo = 'notbar';

$bar = null;

switch ($foo) {
    default:
        echo "default";
        break;
    case 'bar':
        if (!!$bar) {
            echo "true";
            die();
        } else {
            echo "false";
            die();
        }
        break;
}
```

This code will echo `default` and nothing else.

Comment: While you can use `isset()`, if statements work too. See the [type comparison table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). It behaves as `!empty()`

Comment: @Xorifelse I swear I copied his code and ran it, and received `true`. Must be late for me too :)

Comment: @nwilging you didn't get the point.... I am totally aware of what you are writing.

Comment: @nwilging well... ok... what php version?

Comment: And I am seeing `string(4) "else"` after running his code, making this code entirely obsolete.

Comment: @MarkusKottländer I ran it on multiple, 7.0, 7.1, 5.6.

Comment: @MarkusKottländer http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/266b9f9b2bed67cedf4ee8d99f2c3d6bb3e1baa8

Comment: Seems to be working as intended... But I'm with you, not sure what happened at first.